# How to get logs from current thread only in log4j

Tags: java, multithreading, logging, log4j

I want to intercept logs from the specific thread in my application for the certain period of time. I'm using log4j. 
The code below does that, but I'm getting logs from others threads too.

```
                WriterAppender appender = new WriterAppender(new PatternLayout("%d{ISO8601} %p - %m%n"), consoleWriter);

                appender.setName("STR_APPENDER");
                appender.setThreshold(org.apache.log4j.Level.INFO);
                Logger.getRootLogger().addAppender(appender); 
                //Some Logic here (I'm using other classes and jars here and I want to get this logs as well)
                Logger.getRootLogger().removeAppender("STR_APPENDER");
```

I'm aware that Logger.getRootLogger() is not a good solution here, but I don't have any other idea.

Comment: You could use your own appender (maybe just a wrapper) and check the thread that calls it. You'd tell the appender which threads' messages to forward, e.g. by passing the thread or its id to the appender's constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MDC.put.`

eg

```
MDC.put("threadName",Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

Using that you can put thread name.

Using Log4j appender you can print the thread name [%X{threadName} in logs